# Stripe: Confirmation Page

Tags: php, stripe-payments, stripe.net

Good morning,

I'm working to implement Stripe onto my website for payment. Everything has been successful in testing except for one small hiccup: upon taking in the payment, I do not see a page where it can forward to my success page. I have a receipt page set up with a GET variable, but if Stripe detects a meta refresh or PHP header forward, it will fail to process.

The code I used to build this page was based off of here:
http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/so-you-want-to-accept-credit-cards-online--net-25457

Does anyone familiar with Stripe know how I would go about making a receipt page work? Thank you!

Comment: more or less a how to here [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23695085/dynamic-payments-with-stripe/23771492#23771492][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23695085/dynamic-payments-with-stripe/23771492#23771492

Answer (score 0):

Success and failure are handled completely by your server-side code. Both [Stripe.js](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe.js) and [Stripe Checkout](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout) simply generate a card token and POST it to the form action you've specified.

It's then your job to create a charge using that token and display a success or failure page.

Comment: After the token is generated then payment is to be made or when the token is generated the payment is successful??

Answer (score 0):

To expand upon @colinm ,
You send the card information to stripe which creates a token and returns it to where the form submits.

```
// Boom! We passed the basic validation, so request a token from Stripe:
Stripe.createToken({
  number: cardNumber,
  cvc: cardCVC,
  exp_month: $('#expiration-month').val(),
  exp_year: $('#expiration-year').val()
}, stripeResponseHandler);

// Prevent the default submit action on the form
return false;
```

Afterwords, you can make a charge or a customer with the token

```
// Get all the values from the form
$token = $_POST['stripeToken'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$firstName = $_POST['firstName'];
$lastName = $_POST['lastName'];
$price = $_POST['price'];
```

and don't forget to set the api key somewhere before the charge/customer!

```
$trialAPIKey = "your_Secret_testkey";  // These are the SECRET keys!
$liveAPIKey = "your_Secret_Livekey";

Stripe::setApiKey($trialAPIKey);  // Switch to change between live and test environments
```

after the second form is where you should have it returning to a success page (use a try/catch loop for errors and have the redirect for success outside those)