# Dynamic Payments with Stripe

Tags: javascript, php, payment, stripe-payments

I"m struggling with Stripe. I'm using PHP and I'm trying to set up a simple store, with no CMS. Wondering how I can pass the amount into charge.php so I can charge different amounts for different products. Here's my code:

```
$charge = Stripe_Charge::create(array(
      'customer' => $customer->id,
      'amount'   => 1900;,
      'currency' => 'gbp'
  ));
```

Here's the code from index.php - I would like to charge the customer whatever is in "data-amount" on the form below. Not quite sure how to do so.

```
<form action="inc/charge.php" method="POST">
    <script
            src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
            data-key="<?php echo $stripe['publishable_key']; ?>"
            data-amount="1900"
            data-currency="GBP"
            data-name="Pure - Tumblr Theme"
            data-allow-remember-me="false"
            data-description="Premium Tumblr Theme"
            data-image="/128x128.png">
          </script>
</form>
```

Answer (score 3):

More comprehensive, go from index.php to charge.php rather than the reverse.

```
<?php
 #set your variables
 $amount       = 500;
 $name         = 'My Company';
 $currency     = 'gbp';
 $description  = 'Value Plan';
 $uid          = get->your->uid;
 $email        = get->your->email;
?>

<center><form action="../charge.php" method="post">
<!-- make these hidden input types for the post action to charge.php -->
<input type="hidden" name="amount"      value="<?php echo $amount?>">
<input type="hidden" name="name"        value="<?php echo $name;?>">
<input type="hidden" name="currency"    value="<?php echo $currency;?>">
<input type="hidden" name="description" value="<?php echo $description;?>">
<input type="hidden" name="uid"         value="<?php echo $uid;?>">
<input type="hidden" name="email"       value="<?php echo $email;?>">

<script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"

        data-key =           "<?php echo $stripe['publishable_key']; ?>"
        data-amount =        "<?php echo $amount;?>"
        data-name =          "<?php echo $name;?>"
        data-currency =      "<?php echo $currency;?>"
        data-description =   "<?php echo $description;?>"
        data-email =         "<?php echo $user->data()->email; ?>"
        data-billing-address =     "true"
        data-allow-remember-me =   "false"
        >

</script>
</form></center>
```

Then in charge.php you can call the input values you hid in index.php

```
<?php
$token        = $_POST['stripeToken'];
$email        = $_POST['email'];
$uid          = $_POST['uid'];
$currency     = $_POST['currency'];
$amount       = $_POST['amount'];
$description  = $_POST['description'];

#This is the standard try catch block stripe suggests
try{
$charge = Stripe_Charge::create(array(
"amount"        => $amount,
"currency"      => $currency,
"customer"      => $charge_to,
"description"   => $description
));

} catch(Stripe_CardError $e) {

$error = $e->getMessage();
// Since it's a decline, Stripe_CardError will be caught
$body = $e->getJsonBody();
$err  = $body['error'];

print('Status is:' . $e->getHttpStatus() . "\n");
print('Type is:' . $err['type'] . "\n");
print('Code is:' . $err['code'] . "\n");
// param is '' in this case
print('Param is:' . $err['param'] . "\n");
print('Message is:' . $err['message'] . "\n");
} catch (Stripe_InvalidRequestError $e) {

// Invalid parameters were supplied to Stripe's API
} catch (Stripe_AuthenticationError $e) {
// Authentication with Stripe's API failed
// (maybe you changed API keys recently)
} catch (Stripe_ApiConnectionError $e) {
// Network communication with Stripe failed
} catch (Stripe_Error $e) {
// Display a very generic error to the user, and maybe send
// yourself an email
} catch (Exception $e) {
// Something else happened, completely unrelated to Stripe
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to charge **whatever** is in `data-amount`? Where do you get that value from? data-amount tells Stripe what the user allows you to charge. amount in Stripe_Charge::create is what you actually charge.

You could populate a hidden input field with the same value as data-amount. But i don't know what you would gain by that.
Your PHP skript should calculate the amount to pay. Don't trust the client. He could change the value of data-amount to pay less, i.e. 50. 
Using the following the charge would work, but client pays 50 pence instead of 1900.

`$charge = Stripe_Charge::create(array(
    'customer' => $customer->id,
    'amount'   => $_POST['hidden_amount']`

Ask Stripe for the total calculated payment. If the client has messed with data-amount the charge will fail.
`'amount'   => $shoppingcart->getTotal();,`